# MYSQL Sort by non alphanumeric

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a site that stores cooking tutorials. one of the columns in the mysql database holds either **Novice, Intermediate, Advanced, Expert.** I'd like to know if there was a way to write the MySQL query to order the results in the above fashion? Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes its possible to write an expression that converts those values into values that can be sorted, and to put that expression into the ORDER BY clause. There are lots of ways to do that. The most portal ANSI-compliant would be to use a CASE expression  e.g. `ORDER BY CASE mycol WHEN 'Novice' THEN 1 WHEN 'Intermediate' THEN 2 WHEN 'Advanced' THEN 3 WHEN 'Expert' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END`.  With MySQL, we have several options for shorter expressions that achieve an equivalent result.e.g. `FIND_IN_SET(mycol,'Novice,Intermediate,Advanced,Expert')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by `INSTR` if its a small table:

```
ORDER BY INSTR('Novice, Intermediate, Advanced, Expert', `colname`)
```

But this will be slow on a large table. Better to just store a numeric value from 1 to 4 and add an `index` on it. Then translate the number to Novice, Intermediate, Advanced, or Expert when needed. Or perhaps two columns but that could lead to differences between the numeric and textual value.